# Remove all style attributes from HTML in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, scrape

I have to load the body of an HTML page without any style attribute and no link images and everything that is not 'plain text. I would like to do it in PHP and tried very solution but I have not solved. I load the html page with an ajax call to my script and then with a regular expression I take the body that then I want this cleared. Can you help me? This is the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "GET"
       url: "core/proxy.php?url="+cerca,              
       success: function(data){
       var body = data.replace(/^[\S\s]*<body[^>]*?>/i, "")
       .replace(/<\/body[\S\s]*$/i, "");
        $("div#risultato").html(body);
    },
      error: function(){
      alert("failed");
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: How about showing us the PHP solution you tried?

Comment: Doing what you describe is, in general, a complicated problem; it's not just a simple regular expression thing.

Comment: Always worth pointing out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I have forgot that the html page are all articles of  these links: http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/11contents.html , http://rivista-statistica.unibo.it/issue/view/467 . And for all other sites that i search i must display the body content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jose Antonio Riaza Valverde I corrected but nothing changes:

```
$.ajax({
            //definisco il tipo della chiamata
            type: "GET",
            //url della risorsa da contattare
            url: "core/proxy.php?url="+cerca,
            //azione in caso di successo
            success: function(data)
            {
                var body = data.replace(/^[\S\s]*<body[^>]*?>/i, "")
                .replace(/<\/body[\S\s]*$/i, "");
                $("div#risultato").html(body);
                clearStyles(document.getElementById('risultato'));

            },
            //azione in caso di errore
            error: function()
            {
                alert("Chiamata fallita");
            }
    });
});
```

and the function:

```
function clearStyles(element) {
element.setAttribute('style', ' ');
element.setAttribute('img', ' ');
element.setAttribute('a', ' ');
for (var i = 0; i < element.children.length; i++) {
    clearStyles(element.children[i]);
}
```

}

Comment: Did you try with jQuery? `jQuery('body *').removeAttr('style');` and `jQuery('img, a').remove();`

Comment: i have tried but nothing to do. Maybe I'm wrong to use removeAttr method. I have used `jQuery('#risultato').removeAttr('style');`

Comment: You must use `jQuery('#risultato *').removeAttr('style');` to apply it all children of `#risultato`.

Comment: No errors but nothing to do. I use jquery after .html instruction

Comment: Can i use XPATH for select the node body from the html and apply a simple css?

Comment: I have used the regular expressions, thanks for help

Comment: Hi all i have solved, i have used goutte and x path for my project. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery to just get the text content of the `body`.

So, in your `success` function, you would take the `data`, convert it to a jQuery-object and insert the text in your div.

```
$('div#risultato').html($(data).find('body').text());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could clear `style` attributes, tag by tag, after insert the `body`:

```
function clearStyles(element) {
    element.setAttribute('style', '');
    for (var i = 0; i < element.children.length; i++) {
        clearStyles(element.children[i]);
    }
}
```

`clearStyles(document.body);`

**http://jsfiddle.net/n9ocxa0g/**

Or directly with jQuery:

```
jQuery('body *').attr('style', '');
```

Comment: Ok Thanks and for remove the links, <img> tags and textbox?

Comment: `jQuery('body a, body img, body input, body textarea').remove();`

Comment: Sorry but with the first function clearStyles when my variable body contains the body of the website i receive an error in setAttribute that safari   tells me that is not a function and the second instruction not work. I copied and pasted your function in my js files and after my instruction data replace i call clearStyles(body).

Comment: How do you get body? With `setAttribute()` you can't use `jQuery`, you should use `document.body` or `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]`.

Comment: Add an id to that div (eg `id="content"`) and call function `clearStyles(document.getElementById('content'));`.

Comment: HI this evening i will try it